Derivation of the consistency term in the DDPM Evidence Lower Bound (ELBO)
I have been studying diffusion models from this tutorial: https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.18103 and trying to derive all results as I read it. Although this tutorial is very comprehensive, it skips many of the derivation steps. I am currently stuck in the derivation of the Evidence Lower Bound (ELBO) terms for variational diffusion model (Page 17). The ELBO consists of 3 terms: reconstruction loss term, prior matching and consistency term. I am struggling with the derivation for the consistency term as I am trying to expand the expectation as an integral over the specified probability distribution $q_{\phi}(x_{1:T}|x_0)$. To simplify the expression, I am using the Chapman-Kolmogorov property for the Markov process, as explained here
$$\int dx_t q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_t)q_{\phi}(x_t|x_{t-1}) = q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_{t-1})$$
Solving the consistency term,
$$E_{q_{\phi}(x_{1:T}|x_0)}\Big[\text{log} \prod_{t=1}^{T-1} \frac{p(x_t|x_{t+1})}{q_{\phi}(x_{t}|x_{t-1})}\Big] = \sum_{t=1}^{T-1} E_{q_{\phi}(x_{1:T}|x_0)}\Big[\text{log} \frac{p(x_t|x_{t+1})}{q_{\phi}(x_{t}|x_{t-1})} \Big] = \sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \int dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_{t-2}dx_{t-1}dx_{t}dx_{t+1}dx_{t+2} \ldots dx_{T} q_{\phi}(x_{T}|x_{T-1}) \ldots q_{\phi}(x_{t+2}|x_{t+1}) q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_{t}) q_{\phi}(x_{t}|x_{t-1}) q_{\phi}(x_{t-1}|x_{t-2}) q_{\phi}(x_{t-2}|x_{t-3}) \ldots q_{\phi}(x_{1}|x_{0}) \text{log} \frac{p(x_t|x_{t+1})}{q_{\phi}(x_t | x_{t-1})}$$
Using the Chapman-Kolmogorov property, I can perform the integral for the indices $t \in$ {$1, \ldots, (t-2)$} $\cup$ { $(t+2),\ldots, (T-1)$}. After these integrations, the expression becomes,
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \int dx_{t-1} dx_{t} dx_{t+1} dx_{T} q_{\phi}(x_T | x_{t+1}) q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_{t}) q_{\phi}(x_{t}|x_{t-1}) q_{\phi}(x_{t-1}|x_{0}) \text{log} \frac{p(x_t|x_{t+1})}{q_{\phi}(x_t | x_{t-1})} 
$$
Question 1: In the above expression, can I perform the integral over the index $T$, as in $\int dx_T q_{\phi}(x_T|x_{t+1}) = 1$? Is this correct?
Let's say, I did perform the integral over index $T$, and proceed further as,
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \int dx_{t-1} dx_{t} dx_{t+1} q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_{t}) q_{\phi}(x_{t}|x_{t-1}) q_{\phi}(x_{t-1}|x_{0}) \text{log} \frac{p(x_t|x_{t+1})}{q_{\phi}(x_t | x_{t-1})} 
$$
$$
= -\sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \int dx_{t-1} dx_{t+1} q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_{t})  q_{\phi}(x_{t-1}|x_{0}) \int dx_{t}  q_{\phi}(x_{t}|x_{t-1}) \text{log} \frac{q_{\phi}(x_t | x_{t-1})}{p(x_t|x_{t+1})}
$$
$$
= -\sum_{t=1}^{T-1} \int dx_{t-1} dx_{t+1} q_{\phi}(x_{t+1}|x_{t})  q_{\phi}(x_{t-1}|x_{0}) D_{KL}(q_{\phi}(x_t | x_{t-1}) \Vert p(x_t | x_{t+1}))
$$
Question 2: Is the above step correct?
The final expression is supposed to look like the following, where the expectation is over $q_{\phi}(x_{t+1, t-1}|x_0)$ but I am not sure how to reduce my above expression to this:
$$
-\sum_{t=1}^{T-1} E_{q_{\phi}(x_{t+1, t-1}|x_0)}\Big [ D_{KL}(q_{\phi}(x_t | x_{t-1}) \Vert p(x_t | x_{t+1})) \Big]
$$
Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Please, ask only one question per post. You can always create multiple posts and reference other posts.

ELBO derivation for DDPM doesn't need the convoluted Chapman-Kolmogorov property for the Markov process, your tutorial also doesn't mention it at all. They key difficulty is to reverse the direction of $q_{\phi}(x_t|x_{t-1})$ in the original consistency term of the ELBO via Bayes rule and one more conditional rv $x_0$. Then the consistency term just takes expectation wrt to the tractable distribution $q_{\phi}(x_t|x_0)$ instead of the original odd $q_{\phi}(x_{t-1},x_{t+1}|x_0)$. Further on you can use the nice property of Gaussians (every type of conditional distribution here is Gaussian) of the forward and reverse consistent Markov chains to get a simple closed form training objective.
